# PHP if else statement to change wordpress loop during certain seasons

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a chunk of PHp code we're using to change out the loop on a WordPress site during specific seasons. So in the winter time, it will display a banner with wording relevant to furnaces, and during the summer it shows a different banner with wording relevant to air conditioners.

These banners and the wording are already setup as a custom post types in the backend and are called by their category IDs into the two loops (4 = summer, and 5 = winter).

The issue we're having is that the loop does not change during the winter months, it just keeps displaying the summer banner and wording. I am thinking there is something I did wrong with this code and I hoping for a bit of guidance into making it work correctly:

```
<ul>

<?php
   $seasontype = array(
           "summer" => "'summer'",
           "winter" => "'winter'"
   );

   $day = date("z");

   $summer_starts = date("z", strtotime("March 1"));
   $summer_ends   = date("z", strtotime("August 31"));

   $winter_starts = date("z", strtotime("September 1"));
   $winter_ends   = date("z", strtotime("February 28"));

   if( $day >= $summer_starts && $day <= $summer_ends ) :
           $season = "summer";
   else :
           $season = "winter";
   endif;

   $seasonheader = $seasontype[$season];

   if($seasonheader = 'summer') {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'header-slide', 'order' => 'ASC', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cat' => 4 );

   $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

   <li>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail("full"); ?>
     <div id="banner-content">
     <div class="container">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
   </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?> <? } else {?>

<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'header-slide', 'order' => 'ASC', 
 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cat' => 5 );

  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

   <li>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail("full"); ?>
     <div id="banner-content">
     <div class="container">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
   </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?> <?php }?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your if statement. You wrote `if($seasonheader = 'summer') {}` a singe `=` is an assignment operator. You need `==` which is a comparison operator. The way you have it written it will always equal true and always display posts for the summer.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I'll try this out.